# HTML / iFrames: IFrame в IFrame не отображается (Dynamics CRM)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

**Добрый день!**

Я пытаюсь средствами HTML отобразить IFrame в IFrame.

```
var iFrameAuth = $('#InlineDialog_Iframe', window.parent.document).contents().find('#iFrameAuth');
    iFrameAuth.css("display","block")
    iFrameAuth.width(w);
    iFrameAuth.height(h);
    iFrameAuth.src = url;
```

Итог:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там ничего не отображается, хотя я указываю валидный src (окрывал в отдельной вкладке)

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки отобразить во втором iframe старницу?**

Answer (score 0):

```
 iFrameAuth[0].src = url;
```

решило вопрос